# where is the modalColor: 'greenYellow'(background ) in popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, bpopup

There is example in [jQuery.bPopup.js](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/24A9b/820/) **Example 2b**

I want to create popup window with  some style text and around the window background ,I try to implement the 
**Example 2b, custom settings: Simple jQuery popup with custom settings (Jamaican popup, relax man)**

```
$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup({
        fadeSpeed: 'slow', //can be a string ('slow'/'fast') or int
        followSpeed: 1500, //can be a string ('slow'/'fast') or int
        modalColor: 'greenYellow'
    });
```

But I miss something.
thanks for any help.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/centerwow/24A9b/820/)

Comment: jsfiddle demo works fine for me.

Comment: Yes, But where is the  modalColor: 'greenYellow'(background ) around the window ?

Comment: if the issue is that the background color is not working, perhaps you should specify that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```
appendTo: 'form'
```

I'm pretty sure the mask (the greenYellow thing) has to be attached to the body.

If you remove it, it works ;)